# Splitting strings in to array by intergers in the string using php

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I have this example string.

```
$string = "There four of them. These are: 1 The first one. Its is the most common. 2 The second one. 3 The third one. 4 This is the last.";
```

I wanted to split into array containing information given in the above `$string`. I want it to look like this.

```
Array ( 
   [0] => The first one. Its is the most common. 
   [1] => The second one.
   [2] => The third one.
   [3] => This is the last.
)
```

Can any help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: explode(". ",$string );

Comment: But the first array contains two dots(.) s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` to split the string by integers, for example:

```
$string = "There four of them. These are: 1 The first one. Its is the most common. 2 The second one. 3 The third one. 4 This is the last.";

$matches = preg_split('/\d+/', $string);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. It counts numbers of characters. But I user print_r() . Thanks.

Comment: But the `$matches[0]` is additional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to select target part of string. The regex select string between two digits.

```
preg_match_all("/\d+([^\d]+)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/v5lnT)